# Function doesn't work after jQuery ajax html injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call on a webpage...

```
    var href=$('.poplight').attr("href");
    $('.poplight').attr("href","#");
    $('.poplight').click(function(){
        $.get(href, function(data) {
                $("#popup-contents").html(data) 
                    // inserts <div id="additionalInfo"> 
                    // <legend id="legend-params">Legend</legend>
                    // <div id="toggle"> This should toggle </div> </div>

            }
        );
    });

</script>
```

On the same page, there is a .js script linked that toggles the #toggle div whenever the legend is clicked. This all works fine on a separate page (just the legend toggle by itself), but I can't get it to work with the ajax call. I'm thinking it has to do with when jquery "attaches" to certain doms... I don't know enough about the innerworkings of jquery to really know for sure.

Here is the external script. I've tried with an onload, adding it inline with html, and a few other variations. These functions are run when the legend is clicked (if you insert an alert('test') after the .show() method, it will display an alert window).

```
$('#toggle').hide();                                            
$("#legend").toggle(
    function() {
       $("#toggle").show("slide", {direction: "up"}, 200);
    }, 
    function() {
       $("#toggle").hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 200);
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try to use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead. This way the handlers will be bound to elements that are created on the fly as well. The way you are doing it right now will only bind the behavior to elements that are present on DOM ready.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796799/jquery-not-working-in-ajax-loaded-divs

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses... will give them a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments listed above helped me solve the problem (I think they were converted to comments by SO's "algorithm"... would have marked them as answers).
I essentially changed:

$("#legend").toggle(...)
to

$("#legend").on('click', functionX()...)
where functionX that was pretty much a glorified if statement that hid some things if a global variable was true or false. Maybe not the cleanest solution, but it did the job.